# opencv: installation of package libtiff

Tags: opencv, operating-system, anaconda, raspberry-pi3, libtiff

This package is installing opencv and here it says that libtiff4 has no installation.
[image]

And here i set from libtiff4 to libtiff 5 so it says package broken
i used all update commands again but not recovering. can any one suggest me where am i mistaken ?

[image]